# Constructing an average equation - Standardized Test

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

A question in the standardized test is:

> The average of $n$ numbers is $a$. If $x$ is subtracted from each number the average will be
>
> a) $(ax)/n\quad$  b) $(an)/x\quad$  c) $an-x\quad$  d) $n-x\quad$  e) $a-x$

The answer to this is e) $a-x$.

Could anyone please help me figure how the author got this answer ??

Comment: you should show what you have attempted.

Comment: I cant figure out how to approach this problem. As I already mentioned its a standardized test question.It is very unlikely that i would post questions here without attempting and re-attempting them first.

Comment: Probably common sense would take care of it. The average amount of money in the bank accounts of $47$ people is $2000$. If $15$ is taken from each account, what is the average left?

Comment: @Rajeshwar, I have looked at all your questions. I think if you spend a little more time (and effort), you should be able to solve them.

Comment: @picakhu, at first I was not inclined to agree with you. However, after looking at his questions, I also do not feel he is posting in the spirit of Math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n_1, \dots, n_m$ be the $m$ numbers. That the average of the numbers is $a$ means that
$$\frac{n_1 + \dots + n_m}{m} = a.
$$
Now subtract $x$ from each number and compute the average and you get:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(n_1- x) + \dots +(n_m  - x) }{m} &= \frac{n_1 + \dots + n_m - mx}{m} \\ &= \frac{n_1 + \dots n_m}{m} - \frac{mx}{m} \\ &= a  - x
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the original numbers were $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$, so that the average is $$a=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}.$$

Now, if we subtract $x$ from each of the numbers, we're going to be averaging $x_1-x$, $x_2-x$, ..., $x_n-x$, which gives
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(x_1-x)+(x_2-x)+\cdots+(x_n-x)}{n}
&=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n-n\cdot x}{n}\\
&=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}-\frac{nx}{n}\\
&=a-x.
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer I think i am almost there.How did you get a-x from the second last step ? Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: I added a step in between what had been the last two steps—does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes it does. I really appreciate the help